# Webpack Code Splitting: Does it do anything? Seems like no effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, production

new to webpack and react here. I followed this [medium article](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/automatic-code-splitting-for-react-router-w-es6-imports-a0abdaa491e9#.npmo56upa) to create code splitting in react router. It seems like it has no effect though because my app still has to load the whole bundle.js file synchronously on the initial page load. Any tips for reducing this load time? bundle.js is 2.2mb in dev but prod is about 400kb at the moment after uglifying it.

**Simulating a regular 3G connection on network tab**

[image]

**router.js**

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
      {
        path: 'signup',
        getComponent(location, cb) {
          System.import('./modules/App/components/Authentication/Login.js')
            .then(loadRoute(cb))
            .catch(errorLoading);
        }
      }
    ]
  }  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these plugins to reduce your duplicate codes

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
```

**Deduce plugin** will find duplicate files and codes and merge them into single unit.
**Uglify plugin** will uglify your code in production.

Comment: That definitely reduces the size of the bundle.js file but I'm worried that as it gets bigger and bigger this synchronous loading of the bundle.js file will really hamper load-times :(

Comment: Use async loading if you required unblockable loading <script src="bundle.js" async></script>

Comment: is there a way to split the bundle.js file into several other files?

Comment: use common modules like react, react-router, jquery, lodash, etc. in single file and your script in another file. Otherwise there is no other way with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

So I went through the webpack docs and used several plugins. Managed to get the file sizes down

> from 2.2mb to 92kb and speed up the loading times by 10x.

Here is my webpack.config file now.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    js: [ './src/index.js' ],
    vendor: [
      'react', 'react-router', 'react-redux', 'toastr', 'lodash'
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/prod'),
    publicPath: '/dist/prod',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }, 

  plugins: [ 
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        filename: 'vendor.js',
        minChunks: Infinity,
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
      new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
      new CompressionPlugin({
          asset: "[path].gz[query]",
          algorithm: "gzip",
          test: /\.js$|\.html$/,
          threshold: 10240,
          minRatio: 0.8
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), 
    ],

  module: {
    rules: ...
  }
}
```

EDIT: After moving fonts from google to local fonts folder, removing duplicate font calls from libraries like simple-grid and using @font-face, managed to really cut down the load times.

> Now 5.5s on regular 3G compared to 27s before. 80+% reduction in load-times.

[image: new regular 3G load-times]